# unable to get enter and get value in REACT.js

Tags: reactjs, state

I am new to ReactJS and trying to build a sample application
I am unable to get enter the value in textbox and unable to get the value in alert. Am I doing something wrong.  I have tried the example given on React.Js Form, but not working.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class AddNewStudent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value:''};

        this.OnSubmit = this.OnSubmit.bind(this);
    }


    OnSubmit(event){
        alert('name value is : '+this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.OnSubmit}>
                <fieldset className="Student-Form" id={this.props.id}>
                    <legend className="Legend">Add mew student</legend>
                    <div>
                        <div className="Block">
                            <div className="Float-Left">
                                <label>
                                    <span>Name : </span>
                                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} />
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="clearFix" />
                        <div className="Block">
                            <div className="Float-None">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddNewStudent;
```

Answer (score 2):

please change :

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} />
```

to:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange = {this.onChange}/>
```

In your class, add the 'onChange' function:

```
onChange(e){
  this.setState({
    value: e.target.value
  })
}
```

and in your constructor:

```
this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
```

Edit 1:
  please check my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/iamnotstone/pen/aYLoRX)

Edit 2:
  If you have too many inputs, you can use a function like this:(it's just a rough example, in real world I'll create a new component to handle this together)

```
//in your constructor
  this.state = {}
//in class 'controlled component way'
  createInput(num){
    let inputArray = []
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i ++){
      inputArray.push(<input key = {i} name = {i} onChange = {this.onChange} value = {this.state[i] || ''} />)
    }
    return inputArray
  }

  onChange(e){
    let key = e.target.name
    let newState = {}
    newState[key] = e.target.value
    this.setState(newState)
  }

  // in your render function
  return <div>
      {this.createInput(100)}
    </div>
```

check my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/iamnotstone/pen/rdJGoy) for this example

and of course you can also do this using uncontrolled component.
[controlled component and uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Comment: Hi I have tried this thing but it wasn't working at all. When I try all this then I am unable to add any text any value in text box on html and when I remove the "value={this.state.value}" then I am able to enter some value in html input

Comment: I had made a example code in codepen. And edited in my answer. please check it.@ManishKumarNamdev

Comment: Thanks but does it means if I am creating a form and I have 10 input controls then I need to make 10 onChange events to make the setState... isn't it weird.. or may be I am not doing well..  

If general if you add one html input type of text control in notepad and save it as html and run it, then you see a html page with input box and you are able to enter the text.. simple. how is it different than this?

Comment: Also when I changed the code like this: 
I have placed this line this.setState({value:event.target.value}); inside the OnSubmit method and removed the onChange method from input box then again unable to enter the text

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem.I had added a new method to do this by using a 'ref' for another <input> in my codepen example. please check it. If you have many inputs , you can also make a function to do this for you.

Comment: I edited my answer , and added a new example to handle many inputs as described above. please check it.@ManishKumarNamdev

Answer (score 0):

You can either bind `onChange` event to your input or `setState` when submiting the value , you cant change the state like that

Change your code to something like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class AddNewStudent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value:''};

        this.OnSubmit = this.OnSubmit.bind(this);
    }


    OnSubmit(event){
      this.setState({value: this.refs.infield.value},()=>{
        alert('name value is : '+this.state.value);
      })

        event.preventDefault();
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.OnSubmit}>
                <fieldset className="Student-Form" id={this.props.id}>
                    <legend className="Legend">Add mew student</legend>
                    <div>
                        <div className="Block">
                            <div className="Float-Left">
                                <label>
                                    <span>Name : </span>
                                    <input type="text" ref = "infield"/>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="clearFix" />
                        <div className="Block">
                            <div className="Float-None">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddNewStudent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi to get the value add a name to the input and an onChange function to set the  value to the state and then do what evere you want in onsubmit function
I cant write you a working code now because I'm using my phone but my this Will help

```
onfieldchange(e) {
```

this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

}

onaSubmit(){
//do your code here

}
....
....

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" value={this.state.firstName} />
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle form elements in reactjs:
Controlled and uncontrolled components(using refs).In controlled component approach ,you have to add the state of the input field to the input field value and onChange event to it, which is the one you are trying to do.Here is the working code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class AddNewStudent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          firstname:''
        };

        this.OnSubmit = this.OnSubmit.bind(this);
        this.OnChange = this.OnChange.bind(this);
    }


    OnSubmit(event){
        alert('name value is : '+this.state.firstname);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    OnChange(){
      this.setState({
       [e.target.name] : [e.target.value]
      });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.OnSubmit}>
                <fieldset className="Student-Form" id={this.props.id}>
                    <legend className="Legend">Add mew student</legend>
                    <div>
                        <div className="Block">
                            <div className="Float-Left">
                                <label>
                                    <span>Name : </span>
                                    <input type="text" 
                                      name="firstname"
                                      value={this.state.firstname} 
                                     OnChange={this.OnChange}
                                    />
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="clearFix" />
                        <div className="Block">
                            <div className="Float-None">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddNewStudent;
```